# Access explicit definition of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to access the explicit definition of a variable, in order to print it as a string in a log file.

In order to clarify a bit better what I would like to get as output I will give an example.

```
#Let's say I define the following variable: 
my_dict = dict(zip(list_1,list_2))

#The desired output would be:
'dict(zip(list_1,list_2))'
```

```
#Another example:
df_concat = pd.concat([df_1,df_2])

#Desired output:
'pd.concat([df_1,df_2])'
```

Comment: `'dict(zip(list_1,list_2))'`?

Comment: Realistically I think the only way to do that is to put those things into the log message yourself, assuming you want it logged immediately after setting the value. If you want to be passed a variable from somewhere else and then log how the current value was assigned to it then that seems like something that wouldn't be impossible. Python doesn't keep track of things like that for you.

Comment: Can you add an example how you would call your magical "variable source code finder" function? E.g. would you call it as ``magic(my_dict)`` or ``magic("my_dict")`` or some other way? What result do you expect for looking up ``my_dict2`` after doing ``my_dict2 = my_dict``?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very hacky and works only for simple cases, but here is a proof-of-concept :

```py
import re
import traceback


definitions = {}


def get_name_and_definition(line: str):
    assign_regex = re.compile(r"([^=]*)=\s+remember_definition\((.*)\)")
    match = assign_regex.match(line)
    assert match is not None, "unhandled case : " + repr(line)
    return match.group(1).strip(), match.group(2).strip()


def remember_definition(value):
    caller_frame = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]  # -1 is this line
    name, definition = get_name_and_definition(caller_frame.line)
    definitions[name] = definition
    return value


list_1, list_2 = [1], [2, 3, 4]
my_dict = remember_definition(dict(zip(list_1,list_2)))
print(definitions["my_dict"])  # dict(zip(list_1,list_2))

my_dict = remember_definition({"redefinitions": "works too"})
print(definitions["my_dict"])  # {"redefinitions": "works too"}
```

Limitation :

```
my_tuple = remember_definition(
    (1, 2, 3, 4)
)
# AssertionError: unhandled case : '(1, 2, 3, 4)'
```

Comment: See also a similar answer of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873290/arrange-a-python-object-to-discover-what-name-it-is-assigned-to/70879972#70879972